# Print how data is sent through form

Tags: html, ajax, form-submit

I want to submit a form via AJAN to an external plugin. However this plugin has some mandatory fields to validate the submission.

The normal  flow - without ajax- works fine, so I was wondering how this data is being sent so I can pass the same names and attributes through AJAX too. Hoe can I figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are wondering how standard form posting works, if so then this article provides quite a good explanation [Mozilla developer network - Sending and retrieving form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

In short, forms are most commonly submitted with either **GET** or **POST** http methods.

- GET

Get gathers all the field data from the form and makes a request to server embedding all the data in the URL it self. ex `foo.com?field_name=data&field_name2=data2`

- POST

Post delivers all the data in HTTP request body (that part after the headers and space. [Example HTTP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session))

```
//HTTP header example
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 138
```

Usually the data is encoded in the same manner `field_name=something&field_name2=something+else`

If you want to understand what kind of data your browser is sending to the server you could use the browser network inspector (Accessible usually by pressing f12) [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) [chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance) to see the request body/url and then use the same data in your ajax request.

Comment: yeah, I didn't know I could find this in the inspector! Thank you very much!